# tsql 2012 join 8 tables implicitly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am trying to understand how the following t-sql 2012 with an implicit join is currently executed in production currently:

```
SELECT  distinct Cyear
FROM     dbo.Individual INNER JOIN
              dbo.Course INNER JOIN
              dbo.CalendarYear ON dbo.Course.CalendarYearID = dbo.CalendarYear.CalendarYearID
      AND CalendarYear.endYear >= (SELECT DISTINCT A.endYear FROM CalendarYear A WHERE
              A.active = 1)
      INNER JOIN
              dbo.Cust ON dbo.CalendarYear.CustID = dbo.Cust.CustID INNER JOIN
              dbo.BridgeCust ON dbo.Course.CourseID = dbo.BridgeCust.CourseID ON 
              dbo.Individual.StudID = dbo.BridgeCust.StudID INNER JOIN
              dbo.User INNER JOIN
              dbo.BridgeUser ON dbo.User.UserID = dbo.BridgeUser.UserID
              ON dbo.BridgeCust.CourseID = dbo.BridgeUser.CourseID
```

There is no direct join for the dbo.Individual with the dbo.Course table. The first time the dbo.Individual
is being joined is with the BridgeCust table. The bridgeCust table is only setup for key to the of this
table plus the key to the dbo.Individual and the dbo.Course table.

Thus would you explain to me how implicit join is setup?

Would you write the sql to show me the sql is setup to really be executed explicitly?

Comment: Do you have any foreign keys defined between those tables?

Comment: Does that actually run? I'm fairly certain you cannot use an `INNER JOIN` without a subsequent `ON`. That appears to be incorrect syntax to me.

Comment: yes this does run. I think the order of joins is changed by the execution plan. Thus, I believe the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what is happening

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Cyear
FROM dbo.Individual
INNER JOIN dbo.Course
        INNER JOIN dbo.CalendarYear
            ON dbo.Course.CalendarYearID = dbo.CalendarYear.CalendarYearID
           AND CalendarYear.endYear >= (
                                        SELECT DISTINCT
                                               A.endYear
                                        FROM CalendarYear AS A
                                        WHERE A.active = 1)
        INNER JOIN dbo.Cust
            ON dbo.CalendarYear.CustID = dbo.Cust.CustID
        INNER JOIN dbo.BridgeCust
            ON dbo.Course.CourseID = dbo.BridgeCust.CourseID
ON dbo.Individual.StudID = dbo.BridgeCust.StudID
INNER JOIN dbo.[User]
        INNER JOIN dbo.BridgeUser
            ON dbo.[User].UserID = dbo.BridgeUser.UserID
ON dbo.BridgeCust.CourseID = dbo.BridgeUser.CourseID;
```

Or rewrite it as below and it may be even more clear.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Cyear
FROM dbo.Individual
INNER JOIN (SELECT dbo.BridgeCust.StudID,dbo.BridgeCust.CourseID FROM dbo.Course
        INNER JOIN dbo.CalendarYear
            ON dbo.Course.CalendarYearID = dbo.CalendarYear.CalendarYearID
           AND CalendarYear.endYear >= (
                                        SELECT DISTINCT A.endYear
                                        FROM CalendarYear AS A
                                        WHERE A.active = 1)
        INNER JOIN dbo.Cust
            ON dbo.CalendarYear.CustID = dbo.Cust.CustID
        INNER JOIN dbo.BridgeCust
            ON dbo.Course.CourseID = dbo.BridgeCust.CourseID) F1
ON dbo.Individual.StudID = F1.StudID
INNER JOIN (SELECT dbo.BridgeUser.UserID, dbo.BridgeUser.CourseID FROM dbo.[User]
        INNER JOIN dbo.BridgeUser
            ON dbo.[User].UserID = dbo.BridgeUser.UserID) F2
ON F2.CourseID = F1.CourseID;
```